# Getting fields and their values in an object via reflection Java

Tags: java, reflection

I have an Object in java and it has multiple fields i do not know their types. I am using reflection to get the fields and their values but it isn't working as it seems to be.

```
Object obj = gettingObjectFromSomeMethod();
    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true); 
            Object value = field.get(obj); 
            if (value != null) {
                System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + value);
            }
        }
```

output:

```
serialVersionUID=8683452581122892189
DEFAULT_CAPACITY=10
EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA=[Ljava.lang.Object;@5649fd9b
DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA=[Ljava.lang.Object;@6adede5
elementData=[Ljava.lang.Object;@2d928643
size=4
MAX_ARRAY_SIZE=2147483639
```

but when i print the object it gives the following output

```
[{long_name=Los Angeles, short_name=Los Angeles, types=[locality, political]}, {long_name=Los Angeles County, short_name=Los Angeles County, types=[administrative_area_level_2, political]}, {long_name=California, short_name=CA, types=[administrative_area_level_1, political]}, {long_name=United States, short_name=US, types=[country, political]}]
```

I want to get the value of these fields.. Please suggest what to do

Comment: It seems  your class of your _object_ implements a neat toString. why not call it?

Comment: Probably the second output does not show *fields* of the object but an interpretation of its fields.

Comment: @Jayan toString will not be helpful. I need to get only short_name

Comment: can you please provide gettingObjectFromSomeMethod and which class you convert into object

Comment: @JekinKalariya its actually GoogleApi response method getAddress_components() which returns the object

Comment: then i think for elementData you need to excecute your login again , i mean kind of nested loop

Comment: nested loop on which element? @JekinKalariya

Comment: still not working

Comment: please find my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested the code it is returning list as object response so you can do like below. however if you want specific field you can specify if condition in inner for loop with field.getName().

```
if(obj instanceof List){
    List myList = (List) obj;// this is your object which return from gettingObjectFromSomeMethod


            for (Object object : myList) {
                for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);

                        System.out.println("field_Name"+
                        field.getName() + "field_Value"+field.get(object));
                }
            }
}
```

If this solution not work then please print `System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());` and let me know which time it returns

Comment: Thanks its working now but the only thing that is missing in output is the short_name field and its value. 
output: 

`field_Name serialVersionUID field_Value 3801124242820219131
field_Name head field_Value long_name=Los Angeles
field_Name tail field_Value types=[locality, political]
field_Name accessOrder field_Value false
field_Name serialVersionUID field_Value 3801124242820219131
field_Name head field_Value long_name=Los Angeles County
field_Name tail field_Value types=[administrative_area_level_2, political]`

Comment: The possible reason of this is it could be private variable of server side class, will let you know if i found any good thing for this.if this will helful to you then kindly raised vote for that

Comment: Mavric I have just verified it should work with private member as well, kindly make your that your list has  short_name value in it by printing in log

Comment: its just not getting somewhere as when i did `object.getClass().getField("short_name")` it gives `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: short_name`